# One pulse to ON/OFF bistable latching relay

Tags: relay, pulse, latch

I've been trying to design a latching relay driver circuit, with using a push-button switch. Basically when the circuit is powered on, first press in push-button switch make the relay SET, then the second press will make the relay RESET state.

I've searched online and find this normal relay driving solution. But I couldn't figure out how to implement this into single coil and/or dual coil latching relay. I guess dual coil latching relay is easier to drive than the single coil one.
[image: Push-button relay control]

Any help is appreciated. (if possible please provide falstad simulation)

Comment: switch to shunt cap and pullup R to D FF Clk is /2 functional toggle

Comment: Nowadays the most sensible way to do things like this is probably with a $0.50 microcontroller. Traditionally you would use a T flipflop (which can also be made from a JK or D flipflop)

Comment: @immibis I've been looking at maxim drivers, they're pretty easy way to drive latching relays, but I think they're overpriced. https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/3288

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. Discrete, D FF /2 counter   Astable FF

Choose whatever Relay meets your needs and select Base R to drive 5% of Coil current. Use Darlington and 1% if this exceeds 20mA.

Avoid crosstalk of power grounds between Relay and CMOS ,  like the plague.

[image]

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/y9fd3ztw

Comment: Many thanks @Tony, I've been thinking of using open drain DMOS(tpic6c595) instead of darlington(uln2803a + 74hc595), to avoid extra 8bit shifter chip. Do you think this is suitable, or could you recommend any better way to drive eight latching relays ?

Comment: what relays ? ?

Comment: ah sorry, dual coil latching relays

Answer (score 1):

can't remember where i found this image, so credit to whoever was the original author[image]

Comment: Hi Antony, welcome to EE.SE. Can you provide some explanation of the circuit, and how does this circuit answer OP question. Posting only a circuit without any context or explanation is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

The dual coil relay will need two NPN transistor switches similar to your J1. One for SET and one for RESET.

The single coil probably requires coil voltage reversal for SET and RESET. This requires a H-bridge arrangement and, while the relay is simpler, the switching electronics is more complex.

Comment: a latching relay has another advantage ... no power needed to keep it latched