# How can I make a circuit that works like a pushbutton without a pushbutton?

Tags: circuit-design, switching, pulse, toggle-switch

I am trying to make a circuit that would do the job of pushing a pushbutton just once but without a pushbutton in order to make it automatic.

A sensor activates it, and a latching relay circuit gets activated with that single "push", but in order to reset the relay circuit to put it back on its initial position, the push sent originally has to be one and just one.

One pushbutton turns the dc motor (or whatever) on, and the other resets it.

Now, imagine you would replace the turn-on pushbutton with the single-"push" circuit I want. How would I do that?

Comment: Your description is not correct for what a push button does. No push button sends just one single pulse, every switch has a characterstic called "bounce". Read more about it here, and edit your question to show what you actually need: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/switch-bounce-how-to-deal-with-it/

Comment: Besides, for you application, the number of pulses do not matter as long as both inputs are not activated together. Final note: that circuit diagram is very hard to follow. Consider using the built in circuitlab schematic editor which you can access through the formatting bar when writing a question

Comment: Draw your schematic more clearly. You can use inkscape or the option to add an schematic in the question itself.

Comment: So replace the latching relay with one that doesn’t.

Comment: This is a classic XY problem as I see it. The op is trying to describe a solution instead of describing the problem. Describe the problem and state what you would like your circuit to do. The wiring diagram doesn't seem to bring anything useful to the party.

Comment: Okay forget the schematic. I want a circuit that does the job of a single-push pushbutton but without having to press a pushbutton manually. That's it.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/360771/one-pulse-to-on-off-bistable-latching-relay

Answer (score 0):

Here's a relay-based circuit.

[image]

Sensor activation energises relay K1.

Its 'NO' contact closes and the capacitor charges through the coil of relay K2.

The result is a single-pulse closure of the 'NO' contact of relay K2.

Sensor deactivation deenergises relay K1 and the capacitor discharges through the 270 Ω resistor.